# No test source specified, please check configuration; group(s):

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

`How to run multiple test suites in a folder using Nightwatch CLI command(--group)`

I ran with the command following command

"./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch -c local.conf.js -g specs/folder --env firefox"

I got the response "`No test source specified, please check configuration; group(s)`"

Answer (score 0):

Put your tests inside a folder with the name of your group: 
e.g. `logingroup`.

To run your test with the `logingroup` run: `./node_modules/.bin/nightwatch -c local.conf.js --group logingroup --env firefox`

There is also a section in the documentation of Nightwatch about groups: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#test-groups

Comment: Thanks for Your quick replay. I fix that issue to provide src_folders with an empty string. after that, I executed the -g group name option in the terminal. it's working fine now